# Как найти элемент в массиве объектов неизвестной вложенности?

Tags: javascript

подскажите пожалуйста как можно с помощью рекурсии вытащить объект с id:3 через findItem (в find для итерации приходит только (3)

```
const items = [
  {
    title: 'Production',
    id: 1,
    subTasks: [
      {
        title: 'Production 1',
        id: 2,
        subTasks: [{ title: 'Production 1 - 1', id: 3 }, { title: 'Production 1 - 2', id: 4 }],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: 'Test',
    id: 5,
    subTasks: [],
  },
]
```

Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Я остановился на этом...

```
function findItem(arr) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].id !== 4) {
            pow(arr[i].subTasks);
        }
        else {
            console.log(arr[i]);
            return;
        }
    }
}
findItem(items)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```js
const items = [
  {
    title: 'Production',
    id: 1,
    subTasks: [{
      title: 'Production 1',
      id: 2,
      subTasks: [{
          title: 'Production 1 - 1',
          id: 3
        },
        {
          title: 'Production 1 - 2',
          id: 4
        }
      ],
    }, ],
  },
  {
    title: 'Test',
    id: 5,
    subTasks: [],
  },
]

function findTaskById(id, arr) {
  let result = arr.find((obj) => obj.id === id)

  if (!result) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i].id === id) {
        return arr[id]
      } else if ('subTasks' in arr[i]) {
        result = findTaskById(id, arr[i].subTasks)
        if (result) {
          return result
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return result
}

console.log(findTaskById(1, items))
console.log(findTaskById(3, items))
```

**UDP**
Обновил с учётом комментария от Laukhin Andrey

Comment: Нет, нет, так не пойдет. Функция, в общем случае, нерабочая. Верните обратно объект id=5 в конец списка и второй вызов вернет undefined. Потому что вы не возвращаете результат сразу, как объект найден, а продолжаете поиск дальше. Вторая проблема - избыточность функции. У вас сначала цикл поиска при помощи `find()`, затем второй цикл, где происходит та же проверка.